# How do I add item into the array in C++ with unlimited size?

Tags: c++

In python, there's a function call **append** to add an item into the back of the list. Is there **similar function in C++** to add an item into the array? Or is there any other **alternative method** so that I can add item into an array with undefined size?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int list1[] = {1,2,3,4};
    //a function that add an item at the back of the array;
    cout<<list1[4]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array is fixed size, and cannot be appended to.  A `std::vector` is dynamic, and can be appended to.

Comment: `std::vector` has methods called `push_back()` and `emplace_back()`. `std::deque` also supports `push_front()` and `emplace_front()` on top of that.